# How to make Goland fill struct fields with defined type,not with nil

Tags: struct, field, goland

When I use Goland to initialize a structure,I can use Alt+Enter to auto fill the fileds.However,when the field is a slice or map,it will be fill with nil.So I have to go to the struct define to see the field define and copy it ,sometimes it can be very messy. Is there any way to auto get the field define without jump to the struct define?

I tried to search some Plugins but not useful.

Comment: You can delete `nil`, invoke completion (Ctrl+Space) and select `map[type]type` element: https://imgur.com/a/zyRDGlf